# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Appcompat')

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: This is a image of error that I get whenever I built the project. I had Imported the new project and then build the project which gives the error as the Image shown ./]

I am following the Tutorial http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-volley-example/. Please tell me the solution of this error in the project.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat`
```

but better create style `AppTheme` in `styles.xml` with parent `Theme.AppCompat`, because it will make you more customizable

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

and then in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```